# Reasons SFML TCPListener would fail to bind to port?

Tags: networking, tcp, port, sfml

I'm just getting my feet wet with networking however I do understand the terminology. I was in the process of starting a Server-Multiple client project using SFML 2.3.2 in Visual C++ 2015 and got this far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "SFML/Network.hpp"

const unsigned short PORT = 5000;

void Server(void)
{
    sf::SocketSelector TCPSelect;

    // Add listener
    sf::TcpListener TCPListen;
    if (!TCPListen.listen(PORT))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to bind Listener on port " << PORT << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Server();
    return 0;
}
```

Output: *Failed to bind Listener on port 5000*

---

I have used port 5000 for other small network projects, but this is the first time I am using a TcpListener. I tried running the code as is and with everything in the main(). When printing TCPListen.listen directly it returns the error status code. I have tried different ports of course, some that are port-forwarded on my router, some that aren't (if it mattered).

Is this an issue regarding my code? (If so, what are the means of fixing it?) Or is this an issue regarding something else?

Comment: If it really had failed, the reason would have been given in `errno,` which should have been included in your error message, typically via `strerror()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I seem to have answered my own question. My error was in misinterpreting documentation on the subject of TcpListener when setting up my error message.

The function listen() returns **0** if everything works correctly. I cross checked this by printing the listener's port after calling listen(), which returned 5000.